# Problems optimizing a three variable function using python

Tags: python, optimization

I'm trying to minimize a three-variabled function. I don't really care which method to use,
but since I'm no expert I'm using scipy.optimize, which seemed easy to use. My code is the following:

```
from math import e
import scipy.integrate
import scipy.optimize as optimize

def func(y):
    a=y[0]
    b=y[1]
    c=y[2]
    Tx=70
    Abac=lambda x:(a/b)*(e**(b*x)-1)*e**(-c*(x**2))
    A=(a/b)*(e**(b*Tx)-1)*e**(-c*(Tx**2))
    i=scipy.integrate.quad(Abac,0,Tx)
    
    return(A/(1-i[0])-4.808e-4)

solution=optimize.minimize(func,(0.00291*10**(-8),0.46,2.91e-3),method="Powell",tol=1e-12)
```

But when I run it, I do not get a solution:

```
   direc: array([[1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1.]])
     fun: nan
 message: 'NaN result encountered.'
    nfev: 318
     nit: 2
  status: 3
 success: False
       x: array([ 2.618034  ,  3.07782822, -0.615124  ])
```

And I get the following error messages:
overflow encountered in double_scalars
invalid value encountered in double_scalars
It doesn't seem to matter which tolerance or method I use, I tried changing it but with no luck. I think the error might be related to the fact that the equation has a "divide by 0" for certain values for the constants, but I'm not sure of how to solve this.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: when i run the same code i get this:   `RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  return(A/(1-i[0])-4.808e-4)`  what were you expecting ?

Comment: which python version you are using? be careful about the float point calculation in python, you can consider to normalize the value to avoid float point issue

Comment: I was expecting to get the three values for a,b and c that minimize the value for the function. I am using the latest version of python 3

Comment: what exactly the python version, can you run `python --version` to get it. it is common to meet float overflow and underflow issue in float point calculation, you need to find a way to avoid it.

Comment: I have version 3.7.9

Comment: You can add bounds to [scipy.optimize.minimize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html#scipy-optimize-minimize) (with certain solvers), specifying a minimum and maximum value for each of the three variables. You need to find values where division by zero would occur, such as when y[1] = 0, and set bounds to avoid those cases.